# Import facebook profile image via rails oath

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the oath facebook gem to authenticate users in my app: https://omr-altijdheerlijk.herokuapp.com/ This is working right now.

I have also added a name and image field to the user account in my app. The name field is automatically filled with a user's name from facebook. Now I am also trying to import a user's profile picture from facebook to an account in rails by authetication with Facebook. This is not working, see my code below:

my user.rb file

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
# Include default devise modules. Others available are:
# :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable, :omniauth_providers => [:facebook]

has_many :pins

def self.from_omniauth(auth)
  where(provider2: auth.provider, uid2: auth.uid).first_or_create do |user|
    user.provider2 = auth.provider
    user.uid2 = auth.uid
    user.email = auth.info.email
    user.name = auth.info.name
    user.image = auth.info.image
    user.password = Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
  end
end

has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :square => "200x200>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/images/:style/default.jpg"
end
```

my application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
 # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
before_action :authenticate_user!

protect_from_forgery with: :exception
before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?

protected

  def configure_permitted_parameters
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) { |u| u.permit(:name, :image, :email, :password,    :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_in) { |u| u.permit(:name, :image, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
  devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:account_update) { |u| u.permit(:name, :image, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password) }
  end

 end
```

btw, I am also using Devise (for regular login) and Paperclip, ImageMagic and Amazon S3 for uploading and storing images.

Could anyone help what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What is the type of the column image in your table? Make sure its a string

Comment: I have the following fields in my schema  t.string   "image_file_name"
    t.string   "image_content_type"
    t.integer  "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"

Comment: How come your column name is 'image_file_name' but you are using 'image' in your user model ?

Comment: Change     user.image = auth.info.image
 to user.image_file_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have

```
user.image_file_name = auth.info.name
```

and then in your views :

```
<%= link_to image_tag(user.image_file_name), user %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help. It seems I am one step further. I think the image from facebook is being imported right now. However the image is not yet shown in my view. I have the following code in my view

```
 <%= link_to image_tag(user.image.url(:medium)), user %>
```

When I look into the HTML I see the following link for the image:
http://s3.amazonaws.com/altijdheerlijk/users/images/000/000/019/medium/http://graph.facebook.com/10152500285363157/picture?type=square

Comment: Where is the image being saved? In which column? Do you see a facebook URL in that column?

Comment: If the image URL is being saved in image_file_name, then you need to have <%= link_to image_tag(user.image_file_name), user %>

Comment: I added the full answer, please accept it and upvote so that other people benefit from it. Thanks

Comment: Check! btw, my picture is a little bit fuzzy: https://omr-altijdheerlijk.herokuapp.com/users Is this because it not stored in my Paperclip S3 instance but imported directly from facebook. Do you knwo how I can upgrade the visbility of my picture?

Comment: I can't view your picture if I am not signed in !

Comment: But storing the image in s3 will not make it better quality for sure.